# Padrino console: How to search for a specific constant or method

Tags: ruby, irb, padrino, pry

Is there a way to do a search in all initialised constants, available methods, class names etc in a `Padrino` console session? Or any `irb`/`pry` based repl sessions?

---

For instance, I see a method in a generated pages by the name: project_modules, wish to inspect it further in the console. Hoping to find some global holder of all constants/methods in every nested levels, thats specific to or an instance of Padrino (or a selected master class).

Comment: I couldnt understand whats your real intention. If you are looking for pry setup in your padrino condole you can go for gem 'padrino-pry'.

Comment: Sorry to know that I am unclear. Probably this more of a `Pry` question rather than a `Padrino Console` one. My intent is to explore all the available methods/constants available via `Padrino Console`. 

For instance, I wanted to know the methods that were related to localisation. I knew it was under a Module/Class titled `I18n`; but I didn't know its scope, so was going through things like: `MyApp::i18n` and `Padrino::i18n` etc before finding the actual one. So was hoping to find a way to search for all loaded modules and methods in a flat list.